# Godaddy DNS to AWS EC2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, dns

Need help with my web server configuration. I'm using Python Django, Gunicorn, Nginx. DNS Lookup tool shows correct IP. When I go to my domain name it returns Bad Request (400)

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
#GODADDY RECORDS:

Type    Name    Value   TTL     Actions

  1. a  @   11.222.33.444   600 seconds 

  2. a  www     11.222.33.444   600 seconds

#My SETTINGS.PY FILE: 

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['11.222.33.444']

#NGNIX SETTINGS: 

server {

  listen 80;

  server_name 11.222.33.444 domainname.com www.domainname.com;

  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

  location /static/ {

  root /home/ubuntu/Portfolio;
  }

  location / {

      include proxy_params;

      proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/Portfolio/main.sock;

  }

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What I'm doing wrong? It's not working

Comment: If you do a `dnslookup` on your domain name, does it return the IP address from the `A` record?

Comment: When I type in: domainname.com or www.domainname.com
I get: Bad request (400)

Comment: It returns my domain name and the Bad Request (400) error.

Comment: I recommend you start by confirming that your DNS names are resolving as desired. You can then debug nginx if necessary. If you use `nslookup` on Linux or an online tool such as [DNS Lookup](https://www.whatismyip.com/dns-lookup/), does it resolve correctly to your IP address?

Comment: Yes, I just checked it and my IP address comes up correctly

Comment: Okay, so whatever your problem is, it would be related to your web server configuration. I suggest you update your Question and the Title to better explain whatever problem you are experiencing and then somebody should be able to help. (Your question does not currently state your actual problem, it just says "I have been trying to connect to".) Also, you should include your Security Group configuration associated with the EC2 instance. For other tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Will do, thanks John!

Comment: You say "Godaddy domain name not working", but your DNS test proves successful, so that does not appear to be an accurate description of your issue.